# Displaying non-English strings in Android

Tags: java, android, internationalization, android-listview, cjk

My app is English only but some of the data that I am dynamically retrieving and displaying is from a different language (Eg: Korean). I am doing this before adding the string item to a list view:

```
test = new String(item.name.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

When I use the Eclipse debugger to check the test string, I am able to view the string with the appropriate language characters but when I display the listview on the emulator, it turns into garbage.

I've read that Android automatically supports languages like Japanese, Telugu etc so I am assuming that I am doing something wrong here. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why the hell are you doing this? You have a string, encode it in UTF-8 and THEN decode it with the platforms default encoding - this obviously will fail if the default encoding is anything but UTF-8.

Obvious fix: `test = item.name`.

Also correct but rather useless: `test = new String(item.name.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");`

Comment: I was doing just that; adding item.name strings to the listview but that didn't work so kept trying things with a test string.

Perhaps I am missing some language package for the emulator? I am an Android newbie and I have no clue regarding this stuff.

Comment: @TheV Well I'd try it on a real device to see if it's not just an emulator bug. You shouldn't have any problems showing a unicode string on android.

Comment: FYI... It is not displaying correctly on both the emulator and an actual phone.

Comment: @TheV In which case it's quite certain that you've got a bug when reading the data in - probably it's a different encoding (CJS?). Maybe the eclipse debugger guesses the correct encoding of byte streams? Need more code.